# Typescript classes/static properties re-imported when outside directory hierarchy?

Tags: typescript

I'm running into a problem where imports in one part of my hierarchy seem to create entirely new types - that is, they are not part of the same class and don't share static vars.

Suppose I have a directory structure like this:

```
app/
|-main.ts
|-static/
|-|-StaticClass.ts
|-consumer/
|_|-Consumer.ts

otherConsumer/
|-OtherConsumer.ts
```

Main.ts:

```
import { StaticClass } from './static/StaticClass';
import { Consumer } from './Consumer';
import { OtherConsumer } from '../otherConsumer/OtherConsumer';
export class Main {
   constructor() {
      StaticClass.INIT();
      new Consumer();
      new OtherConsumer();
   }
}
```

StaticClass.ts:

```
export class StaticClass {
    public static A:string;
    public static INIT():void {
        StaticClass.A = "Hello";
    }
}
```

Consumer.ts:

```
import { StaticClass } from './static/StaticClass';

export class Consumer {
    constructor() {
        alert (StaticClass.A);
    }
}
```

And OtherConsumer.ts for our example does the same thing as Consumer.ts.

When Main is run, Consumer outputs "Hello" and OtherConsumer outputs "undefined".

If the "static/" directory is moved one up in the hierarchy to be a sibling of "app" and "otherConsumer" (and all the include paths changed accordingly), then both consumers output "Hello". Both also say "Hello" if the otherConsumer directory is moved down into the app directory.

What is going on here? Is OtherConsumer in some other 'require' namespace because it's outside the directory of the main application?

Comment: This is strange.  Can you publish a repository sufficient to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When Main is run, Consumer outputs "Hello" and OtherConsumer outputs "undefined".

Most likely cause is a circular dependency. The Runtime will pass an undefined to resolve it temporarily.

## More

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles

Comment: The consumers don't require each other, they both only require StaticModule, which itself doesn't have any dependencies. Since the first consumer has a "full" copy of StaticModule after the INIT call, why would the second consumer not have one only if it's outside the hierarchy of Main?